# Is there a way to perform aggregate functions on numeric values in a varchar field with leading $ or trailing %?

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset with records coming from another system I have no control over.  In one field there are values like "$200" and "20%".  I want to analyze the numeric data with some aggregate functions (AVG, median, etc.), how do I strip the leading $ or trailing % for the purposes of the calculation without actually removing the characters from the database?

Comment: Yes, but you are going to have to do some string manipulations to remove all that fluff that should not have been in those columns anyway

Comment: I don't disagree with you.  I was simply hoping there was a way to deal with the data as I received it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REPLACE() function in mysql to replace your values with empty string. And, you can use CAST() if need any casting.

```
REPLACE('$', REPLACE('%', str, ''), '') // check both '$', '%' occurrences and replace
CAST(str AS UNSIGNED)
```

If you need to do a specific manipulation over '$' or '%' then you have to check first the '$' or '%' mark in your value using LOCATE(),

```
LOCATE('$', str) > 0 // if '$' in the str
LOCATE('%', str) > 0 // if '%' in the str
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. There are 2 ways to generally make this work:

1. Prior to aggregating, you doctor the string by using REPLACE() to cut out the non numeric parts. This works best if you have a column with fixed non numeric parts, e.g. when you're summing up percentages or similar. Then, once you have a "clean" string, you can cast it as an integer as you like. Consider:

   SELECT CAST(REPLACE('%', '25%', '') AS UNSIGNED) AS Number

With the numbers restored, you can then do something like

```
SELECT  
AVG(CAST(REPLACE('%', myPct, '') AS UNSIGNED)) + '%' AS averagePct
FROM myTable
```

If you need the output to feature the sign again. Doing this doesn't modify any table data.

On a general note however, putting signs into numeric columns is considered bad practice and should be avoided when possible. You can add things like % and $ seperate columns if need be, but you should never mix data types like this, lest you need to do ugly and brittle stuff like what I outlined above.